Overflow while attempting to calculate the Hamming weight in C++
I'm trying to write a short code that calculates the Hamming weight of integers:
class Solution {
public:
    int hammingWeight(int n) {
        if(n==0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            int a=1;
            while(a<=(float)n/2){
                a*=2;
            }
            return 1+hammingWeight(n-a);
        }
        
    }
};

However it gives error for n=2147483645:
Line 9: Char 18: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1073741824 * 2 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior solution.cpp:9:18

I don't understand how, I never need to do 1073741824 * 2  in my calculation. Also my code works if instead of a<=(float)n/2, I just do a<=n/2.

What is purpose of the cast (float)n?

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to familiarize myself with C++ syntax. Let's say I do the cast, why does it no longer work?

If you are a beginner, Leetcode is a wrong starting point of learning C++. Take a book of The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List and your learn that when int is compared with float, the first one is promoted to a float value. Since the whole range int can't be precisely converted to float, a can get 1073741824 and it's equal to 1073741822 when they are converted to float. So a just exceeds n/2.

My question isn't about what is the best book for C++. I'm well aware that leetcode isn't the best resource and I'm not using leetcode to learn C++. My question is why the simple (float) will cause such an error.

The error is because eventually a*=2 will attempt to assign a number to a that is too large to fit in int. I recommend that you learn about the limits of int (and other data types). In particular, what the maximum value it can hold. You don't have to memorize the exact numbers, but you should be familiar with the general concept.

but it won't. by a<=(float)n/2, I will make sure 2*a will never be above n, which is 2147483645 in my case. In fact, if I change it to a<=n/2 it works fine.

@simplylemon not sure it's relevant here, but one difference is that with a<=(float)n/2, a is converted to float to be compared with the float expression (float)n/2. This can change the outcome, v.s. a<=n/2.

but it won't. by a<=(float)n/2, I will make sure 2a will never be above n, which is 2147483645 in my case. In fact, if I change it to a<=n/2 it works fine.* Before making a false statement, what does prevent you from making a simple test: warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'float' changes value from 2147483645 to 2147483648?

I think the problem is the <=. It might work with <.

but why is it that a<=n/2 works? also the  why would the compiler throw an error just because it thinks mistakenly there would be an overflow even though there isn't?

if i do a<(float)n/2 it has no reason to work. in fact it should give false answer for n equals to power of 2.

@simplylemon Your output says this is a runtime error, not a compiler error. So I deleted my previous comment. The compiler could flag this as a possible overflow, but it can't know anything about the actual values of n or a.

@3CxEZiVlQ I did the test using Leetcode's compiler. Why would implicit conversion from 'int' to 'float' changes value from 2147483645 to 2147483648?

@simplylemon Because float is not an exact representation of a number, unlike int.

Most likely the conversion to float loses precision because it cannot hold that many digits. You can test this easily with std::cout << n << float(n)

This question is similar to: Warning about data loss c++/c. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(float)n can express unit differences up to 16777216 (for an IEEE 754 float).  Once past that, rounding may occur.  Compromising numeric fidelity.

Unrelated to the described problem: What value do you expect for hammingWeight(-1)? (I suspect this currently will lead to a stack-overflow, maybe depending on compiler optimization, but you don't have simple tail-recursion, so the compiler needs to figure out some of the logic).

If you are a beginner, here is a simple rule to learn: Never use type float.  Always use type double.  Type float has virtually no advantages, and it has quite a number of traps and pitfalls. Type double quietly overcomes most of those problems.

The difference between a<=(float)n/2 and a<=n/2 is that in the former, a is converted to float to be compared with the float expression (float)n/2.
During this conversion some precision is lost because the 32 bit float representation does not have enough bits to represent 2147483645 accurately.
In this case the float value becomes 2147483648 (the closest value that can be represented in a float) which changes the comparisson outcome.
You can observe this using this minimal example:
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 2147483645;
    float f = n;
    std::cout << std::fixed << f;
}

Output:
2147483648.000000

Live demo
A side note:
A 64 bit double does have enough bits to represent 2147483645, so if you change the cast to double you should get the same result as without the cast (see minimal demo).
You can see some more info about limitations of floating point repesentations here: Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?.

You can compare the number of representable binary digits for numeric types:
#include <limits>

constexpr std::numeric_limits<float> float_meta;
constexpr std::numeric_limits<int> int_meta;

std::cout<< "integer binary digits: " << int_meta.digits;
std::cout<< "float mantissa digits: " << float_meta.digits;

On a typical platform, the values might be 31 and 24. This means that 1<<30 is well beyond the precision of float type.
The expression a<=(float)n/2 promotes(converts) all the integer values (including a) to float, before calculating the result. If the value of a is larger than (1<<24)-1, the conversion to float looses precision, which is considered UB.
Your compile environment is running a sanitizer prior to compiling the code and it captures a problem before even trying to compile the code. Mind the term UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer in the output. Your code failed before even being compiled. This also signals you that the compile environment doesn't tolerate any UB (which is usually ignored by the compiler in home/personal setups). So you have to learn C++ basics (UB included), before trying this challenge.
You can avoid this particular warning/error by validating your number before conversion:
#include <bit>

unsigned int a = 1;
while((std::bit_width(a) < float_meta.digits)
   && (a<=(float)n/2))
{/**/};

or just avoid the cause by not converting to float:
#include <bit>
unsigned hammingWeight(unsigned n) {
    return std::popcount(n);
};

This code only counts the number of 1 bits in an unsigned number. Depending on the platform, std functions in <bit> may use compiler intrinsics that boil the calculation cost down to a single opcode. If the input is supposed to be signed then std::popcount(std::bit_cast<unsigned>(n)) gives the result for full range of signed, with No UB.
